# ¿Cómo comprobar si un registro ya fue dado de alta? (PHP y MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Trabajo en un formulario para dar de alta usuarios, antes de registrarlos intento verificar que no estén registrados, este es código mi:

```php
$qryComprobacion = "SELECT (id_usuario) FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = '".$nameUser."' AND ap_paterno = '".$ap_pat."' AND ap_materno = '".$ap_mat."'";
$num_rows = mysql_num_fields($qryComprobacion, MYSQL_NUM);
```

En teoría esta última línea debería contar cuántas filas tiene mi consulta para después poder pasarlo por una condición.
En cambio sólo me regresa este mensaje de error:

> **Warning: mysql_num_fields() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in C:\AppServ\www\mike\Sistema\conexionAltaUsuario.php on line 20**

Answer (score 3):

Lo primero, ¡Bienvenido!

Debes informarte puesto que la librería `mysql` en `PHP` está obsoleta, en su lugar deberías utilizar `mysqli` o cualquier alternativa: [Documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php)

No obstante, si es la que vas a usar, la solución es sencilla, la función a utilizar es `mysql_num_rows()` a lo que le tienes que pasar un resultado de una `query`, no el string de la `query` directamente:

```
$qryComprobacion = mysql_query("SELECT (id_usuario) FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = '".$nameUser."' AND ap_paterno = '".$ap_pat."' AND ap_materno = '".$ap_mat."'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qryComprobacion);
```

Y ya posterior a eso, harías algo del estilo, ejemplo:

```
if($num_rows == 0) {
    // Registras el usuario
} else {
    // Devuelves un error
}
```

P.D: Te advierto que si el formulario va a ser utilizado por usuarios, deberías filtrar los campos (si no lo haces ya) para prevenir ataques `SQL Injection` con `mysql_real_escape_string($variable)`

Comment: creo que la condicion seria $num_rows = 0. si da mayor que 0, quiere decir que el usuario existe...

Comment: Cierto, lapsus, gracias @gbianchi

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Ya me funciona :)

Comment: Por favor marca como correcta la respuesta, asi otros usuario pueden saber cual fue la solucion a tu problema. Gracias ;)

Comment: Como mejora sería buena idea añadir un `LIMIT 1`  a la consulta ya que en el momento que exista un registro no necesitamos seguir recorriendo la tabla. También sería bueno agregar un índice único obre las columnas `nombre`, `ap_paterno` y `ap_materno`